# Authentication required for the folder

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to access a folder in Linux Apache server and it's coming up with Authenticatio Required prompt.

How do I reset or find this login details in Cent OS VPS server?

Is this made through htpasswd and if so, what is the name of the file created and where can I look this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in the Apache configuration files, located possibly in /etc/httpd/ folder and look for a block of lines like these (probably in a VirtualHost block):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Files"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/passwd/passwords
Require user joe
```

Then the `AuthUserFile` line will tell you where is the file you need to edit to add/remove/update the user through the htpasswd command, i.e. to update 'joe' password

```
htpasswd /etc/httpd/passwd/passwords joe
```